# How can I get the effective capacity of a disk?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I want to clone on block level a hard disk to SSD.

The source disk is a 500 GB Seagate ([ST500LT012-1DG142](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/momentus-fam/momentus-thin/de/docs/momentus-thin-data-sheet-ds1702-10-1307de.pdf)).  The Lenovo solution center on W10/64 shows an effective capacity of 465,76 GB. I don't know if I can trust the number.

As target disk I would like to buy the Crucial MX500 500 GB (CT500MX500SSD1).

The cloning will fail, if the target disk is smaller than the source disk. How can I check the effective capacity of the disks upfront, so that the sizes will fit?

---

I bought the Crucial MX500 BUT this disk is 0,01 GB smaller than the 500 GB Seagate. Therefore, cloning by sector failed. I had to downsize the source disk a bit and the partition cloning worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The effective capacity of disks is reported in a binary(base2) format. It will be lower than the given size in a decimal(base10) format. The size itself is the same, even if Windows and others report it in different ways. 
Check out [this nice article](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/172191en) by Seagate on the given topic.

In short - both disks are 500GB disks and will have the same effective capacity (as reported by Windows). If vendors started reporting sizes with mixed formats, that would be very confusing.

Edit: The link also provides a way to calculate the size.

```
Capacity Calculation Formula

Decimal capacity / 1,048,576 = Binary MB capacity 
Decimal capacity / 1,073,741,824 = Binary GB capacity
Decimal capacity / 1,099,511,627,776 = Decimal TB capacity

Example:
A 500 GB hard drive is approximately 500,000,000,000 bytes (500 x 1,000,000,000).

500,000,000,000 / 1,048,576 = 476,837 megabytes (MB) = 465 gigabytes (GB)
```

Not having the disk on hand would make it hard to confirm; but during my experience with cloning disks (30-40 drives) I've never had a problem when purchasing drives of the same given size (or larger ofcourse) and cloning. More than half of the drives I've cloned were a simple change from a HDD to SSD with the same size.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - Thanks for the constructive feedback. As his reported size equals the 500GB example in the article, and if one assumes the 3TB drive further down in the list only has one partition it adds up. I've cloned plenty of drives (30-40) and never had the issue arise when the disks sizes reported by vendor in a base10 format match. Not having the disk on hand only leaves the calculations left, which would equal the same size given the input is 500GB for both disks.

Comment: My point is this 500GB may be a rounded value in any case; the exact capacities may differ (I've seen such pair of disks). Cloning on a block level will indeed fail if the target drive is smaller, this is a potential issue the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: That's news to me, as I've never seen a clone fail between various disks from different vendors and different sizes. Good to know the problem does exist though. Thanks for the enlightenment.